# Dynamic routing in Processor API using topic from global store

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have the following topology:

```
Topology topology = new Topology();
            
//WS connection processor
topology.addSource(SOURCE1, new StringDeserializer(), new WebSocketConnectionEventDeserializer(), "topic1")
        .addProcessor(PROCESSOR1, Processor1::new, SOURCE1)
        .addStateStore(sessionStoreBuilder, PROCESSOR1)
        .addSink(WS_STATUS_SINK, "sinktopic", stringSerializer, stringSerializer, PROCESSOR1)

//Service discovery
        .addGlobalStore(nodeTopicDiscoveryStoreBuilder, SOURCE3, new StringDeserializer(),
                    new ServiceDiscoveryEventDeserializer(), "compacttopic", GLOBALSTOREPROCESSOR,
                    GlobalStateStoreBuilder::new)

//WS session routing
        .addSource(SOURCE2, new StringDeserializer(), new StringDeserializer(),
                    "topic2")
        .addProcessor(PROCESSOR2, Processor2::new,
                    SOURCE2)
        .addStateStore(userConnectedNodesStoreBuilder, PROCESSOR2, PROCESSOR1);


    streams = new KafkaStreams(topology, kafkaStreamProperties);
```

How can I send data to dynamic topics based on values in `nodeTopicDiscoveryStoreBuilder` from `Processor2` ?

All the resources available are to take from GlobalKTable and not from global store. It's confusing.

Comment: Not 100% sure what your question is? But a `GlobalStore` and a `GlobalKTable` are basically the same thing. -- In `Processor2` you can access the global state like any other state store to do look ups into it to drive you dynamic routing decision.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax Could you please provide a sample code which shows how to choose sink topic dynamically from a global state store from the processor? Another question, hope the sink topics can be dynamic/different in different instances

Comment: `userConnectedNodesStoreBuilder` local store contains nodeId as value and  `nodeTopicDiscoveryStoreBuilder` global store has nodeId as key and topic name as value. So basically it needs to be joined to get the sink topic

Comment: (1) SO is not a code writing service :) (2) As I don't really know anything about your business logic, I can't really help with an example... (3) You can have dynamic sinks (cf `addSink(..., TopicNameExtractor,...);` (4) A "join" is effectively the same as `globalStore.get()`. I would recommend to check out some example: https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples/blob/5.5.0-post/src/main/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/GlobalKTablesExampleDriver.java

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax I am getting error for globalstore while starting app: `The following subscribed topics are not assigned to any members: [compacttopic]`

Comment: Also, using `TopicNameExtractor`, can we choose list of topics? I have requirement to send each message to send to multiple topics, not one.

Comment: If you need to send a message to multiple topics, you cannot use `TopicNameExtractor` --  there is already a ticket to allow for a list of topics: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7578 -- What you can do is, to call `to()` multiple time though: `KStream myStream...; myStream.to("firstTopic"); myStream.to("secondTopic")` -- instead of using hard-coded topic names you can also use `TopicNameExtractor` if you need -- or you could use `myStream.filter(...).to(...)` to express a more dynamic routing.

Comment: I am using Processor API and not streams. Is `to()` available from inside processor?

Comment: For the Processor API, if you want to send message to multiple topics, you can add multiple sinks to a single processor and use `context.forward(...,To.child(...))` to send it to a specific sink.

Comment: I cannot define sinks since the topics will be dynamic and different with each instance deployment. The destination topics is obtained from a `GlobalStateStore`

Comment: You could enrich the message with the topic name (if you need to send it to multiple topics, duplicate the message for each output topic) and than use `TopicNameExtractor` downstream to extract the topic name.

Comment: It would be much easier to store topics mapping in a globalstatestore and then use producer to send to multiple topics from Processor? I used this approach. Streams does make things complex and not straightforward to work with.

Comment: While this is possible, it's not recommended to use your own producer, as KafkaStreams runtime would not know anything about your produced and thus you need to `flush()` every single write to ensure you don't loose data...

Comment: Thinking about this: there are 2 approaches 1) Re-send every message coming to topic to n messages (enriched with destination topic) and then use TopicNameExtractor to route each message to its topic. 2) Just use producer to directly route to required topics by getting topic info from GlobalStateStore. According to you (1) is recommended. What are the performance consequences, additional network usage for replication etc. Why would (2) result in loss assuming that producer has already sent to kafka?

Comment: Because KafkaStreams commits offsets for you, it flushed it's own producer (that buffers data for more efficient writes) before the offset are committed. This ensures that you don't loose data. If you use your own producer and the producer buffers data, KafkaStreams cannot flush your producer and thus might commit offsets before the data is sent -- for this case, if you crash after a commit but before the producer sent the data, you loose those messages. -- The only way to avoid this issue is to flush the producer after each `send()` in your own code what make writing very inefficient.

Comment: Understood. Another point, in dynamic routing, do we have provision to carry forward the custom headers we add to the topics?

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question?

Comment: All the messages contain custom kafka headers added by source system. So when we use streams, does those headers pass on between processors to sink topics?

Comment: Yes, headers a preserved. And you could even modify them by getting them via `context.headers()` and modifying the returned `Headers` object.